# Add to Cart button displaying twice on Shop Page Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, buttons

recently noticed that the add to cart button is appearing twice on my shop page - https://www.widescenes.com/products/nisi-filters/filter-kits/ . Can't work out if it is conflicting with another plug-in. I had originally added the feature by adding code to the function.php file but now do not see it, so assume it has been overwritten. Have tried adding code to hide but this does not work either. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The top one says it's from an Ajax add to cart plugin - do you have something like that, as a plugin or in your theme? Can you search your site's files for 'ajax_add_to_cart'? It's not working though, both add-to-cart buttons refresh the page for me.

Comment: The top one is the one I had originally added via function.php, the bottom one is the one that recently started to appear. If the product is a variable it says "select options' instead - https://www.widescenes.com/products/nisi-filters/circular-filters/ . Silly question but how do I search my site for files 'ajax_add_to_cart"?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help. Have found the issue. It was caused by Pinpoint Booking System. I deactivated and it removed the second row from the shop page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Woocommerce hook for remove add to Cart Button:

You can check below this function , Add your functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'disable_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

    function disable_add_to_cart_buttons() {
      if( is_shop() ) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks HK89, however does not seem to work, no change to the page.

Comment: You can try it.

Comment: I tried it and it did not change, still showing 2 x add to cart.

Comment: You've added a plugin to the cart

Comment: You can deactivate plugin one by one and check it Which plugin conflicts